# Error in name on passport and visa?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas

My passport had an error where my first name is blank and my last name has been mistakenly printed as "Actual_First_Name Actual_Last_Name". When I went for my B1/B2 visa interview, I was asked by my agent to file as:

First Name: FNU

Last Name: Actual_First_Name Actual_Last_Name

I wish to correct this and will file for a new passport and then go through a new visa process.

Would there be any problems if I travel to the US with my current passport and visa before the correction has occurred? Would there be any problems when I re-apply for a B1/B2 later?

Comment: I don't think there should be a problem, and if there is one, it will probably be fairly easy to resolve, but you would surely be more certain to avoid problems if you can correct the passport and get a new visa before your first trip to the US.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: I understand your passport is wrong, but since it sounds like your visa matches it exactly, it should be fine, no?  (FNU is standard for US visas with no first name.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to correct this, as this does happen to quite a few people given it is a FAQ on the visa website:

> If you have only one name or if your name appears in only one line in your passport, then on the visa your full name will only be printed in the surname field and "First Name Unknown", or "FNU," will be printed in the given name field.

([Source](https://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/in-gen-faq.asp#qlistgen18))

If you wish to re-apply again after the correction, there should be no problem if you explain why you are doing re-applying.

Answer (score -2):

To avoid the confusion, I would suggest correcting the passport (which is fairly easy), rather than explaining the situation to wherever you go or taking risks for visa.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for us to trust your suggestion? Like personal experience or a link to and a quote from an official website where they explain this particular situation?

Comment: During my experience of document legalization for different country visas, Govt officials were asking to present additional documents to prove this person with this FName-LName and LName-FName are same person. So to avoid that hassle in future, it would be better to have the corrected passport. @Willeke

Comment: And how much experience is that? 2 visa or 20 visa?

Comment: @willeke It was about 2 visa for two countries

Comment: Correcting the passport alone will not help, and may hurt: doing so will make the passport name different from the visa name. That's never a good plan. Change both, or neither.

Comment: @David As he was asking for future B1/B2 visa applications, corrected passport will hold good for clear names in new visas.